# Pytorch Dist.broadcast does not work - causes rank that is broadcasting to stop working

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm currently running a similar experiment to the one located here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/dist_tuto.html where I'm trying to broadcast an updated tensor at one rank to the rest of the ranks. Here is the code:

```
import os
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
import torch.multiprocessing as mp

def run(rank, size):
    tensor = torch.zeros(1)
    if rank == 0:
        tensor += 1
        # Send the tensor to process 1
        # line causing problem below
        dist.broadcast(tensor=tensor, src=0)
        dist.barrier()
    print('Rank ', rank, ' has data ', tensor[0])

def init_process(rank, size, fn, backend='gloo'):
    """ Initialize the distributed environment. """
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '29500'
    dist.init_process_group(backend, rank=rank, world_size=size)
    fn(rank, size)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = 5
    processes = []
    mp.set_start_method("spawn")
    for rank in range(size):
        p = mp.Process(target=init_process, args=(rank, size, run))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Now, in the ideal scenario, the print statement at the end of run would print "Rank n has data tensor(1.)" for all n of the ranks, but when I run it, for rank 0, the process immediately stops when it reaches the broadcast line, and it prints out "Rank n has data tensor(0.)" for the remaining ranks, meaning the update wasn't received. I'm not sure what is causing this, so any help would be appreciated. My pytorch version is 1.9.0.

Comment: This fails for me too, do you have any updates on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move barrier outside if, it waits for all the threads to collect the barrier which they won't do.